# Android -- What happens when asnctask get cancelled?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

What happens when `AsncTask` get cancelled.

Does it still calls `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: I hope you will get your answer by reading below nice answer, One thing i want to say as per my experience(and as per document) that if you cancelled your task then it is not guarantee that doInBackground will stop its execution so its good practice to check isCancelled() before executing any new line in doInBackground

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the official java doc:

> A task can be cancelled at any time by invoking cancel(boolean).
>   Invoking this method will cause subsequent calls to isCancelled() to
>   return true. **After invoking this method, onCancelled(Object), instead
>   of onPostExecute(Object) will be invoked after
>   doInBackground(Object[]) returns.** To ensure that a task is cancelled
>   as quickly as possible, you should always check the return value of
>   isCancelled() periodically from doInBackground(Object[]), if possible
>   (inside a loop for instance.)

And method java doc:

```
public final boolean cancel (boolean mayInterruptIfRunning)
```

> Attempts to cancel execution of this task. This attempt will fail if
>   the task has already completed, already been cancelled, or could not
>   be cancelled for some other reason. If successful, and this task has
>   not started when cancel is called, this task should never run. If the
>   task has already started, then the mayInterruptIfRunning parameter
>   determines whether the thread executing this task should be
>   interrupted in an attempt to stop the task.
>
> Calling this method will result in onCancelled(Object) being invoked
>   on the UI thread after doInBackground(Object[]) returns. **Calling this
>   method guarantees that onPostExecute(Object) is never invoked.** After
>   invoking this method, you should check the value returned by
>   isCancelled() periodically from doInBackground(Object[]) to finish the
>   task as early as possible.

Answer (score 4):

Answer is **NO** .as doc says:

> [public final boolean cancel (boolean mayInterruptIfRunning)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29) :
>
> *Calling this method guarantees that onPostExecute(Object) is never
>   invoked*. After invoking this method, you should check the value
>   returned by isCancelled() periodically from doInBackground(Object[])
>   to finish the task as early as possible.